# Django migrate error :TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have tried to set a default value to my field but it causes an error.

Files:

**Models.py**

```
        from django.db import models
        from django.contrib.auth.models import User

        # Create your models here.
        STATUS = [
            (0, "Draft"),
            (1, "Publish")

        ]
        class Posts(models.Model):
            title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
            slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
            author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
            content = models.TextField()
            created_on = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True,auto_now=True)
            status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

Comment: Can you share the migration?

Comment: Try changing the brackets of `STATUS` for parenthesis

Comment: Have you tried to delete the migration and create it again? Probably you messed it up somehow.